# The right place to embed a parser : Server or the Client?

Tags: c, server, parsing, client

I'm writing a database management software. It has a client-server architecture where the server has the piece of code to store and retrieve. The client has to get the input from the user, connects to the server and queries it. Now I have a parser that can parse SQL like queries. My question is which is the best place to embed this parser?

#### Option 1-Embedding it in the Server:

Get the queries from the client, pass it untouched to the Server and then parse it and do the needful.

(OR)

#### Option 2-Embedding it in the Client:

Get the queries from the Client, parse it then and there and then pass a command object that has specific fields set reflecting the queries to the server and the server acts upon the data in the command object.

Which is the right way to do?

Comment: Is it always the very same client program, or do you plan apps for different platforms later?

Comment: its the very same client. Nothing more. I'm just trying this whole thing to get to know the internals of the dbms! But what i want to know is like is it design wise right? Or maybe like is it bad in terms of maintanence/efficient etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. If you need to query the server for getting a lot of metadata to do the parsing, then parsing on the client can cause a lot of additional roundtrips (additional to the ones for executing the query itself). On the other hand, if the client can parse the query and make a syntax check beforehand, without talking to the server, you may need less roundtrips than if you need to ask the server first to see if the query was syntactically correct.

Another question is if the parser needs a lot of CPU time; this would be a reason to place it on the client, to avoid getting your server a bottleneck.

And a third thing to consider is how easy it is to use the parser on the client or the server, which may depends to some degree on the programming languages you are using and how you actually do the embedding. I guess this is not a problem in your case (since it is so obvious you would otherwise would have mentioned it).

Answer (score 3):

There is no one right answer.  It depends on what you want to do.

If I understand you correctly, you're building a system that allows users to form SQL queries and submit them to your DBMS server.

If the users can be trusted to not submit malicious "DELETE FROM TABLE" commands, then either of your options would work.  If you have untrusted users, you have a lot of sanitizing work to do before you submit the query to the database.  The sanitizing **must** be done on the server.

Other concerns were mentioned in the comments, like how many different operating systems you want the client to run on.

In general, your client is untrusted and your server is trusted.  Generally, you will put as much processing as you can on your server, mostly for security reasons, somewhat for consistency reasons.  Performance will suffer.

If top performance is your primary concern, then put as much processing as possible on the client.  This allows you to serve the most clients with a given server.  However, security and consistency will suffer.

Comment: Why should validating a command object (generated by the client parser) be less secure than validating an unparsed query? I agree, sanitizing must be done on the server, but that is true for both of the alternatives the OP mentioned.

Comment: @Doc Brown: If you're talking about both validations happening on the server, they're both secure.  Client verification can be bypassed (the command object generated by some other software).

Comment: Well, if I got this right, OP asked "Where to do the parsing?" and you answered "Do verification on the server." So if the OP meant accidentally "verification" (though he wrote parsing), your answer may fit to the question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no one right answer, but keep in mind that:

- Client must not be trusted. In any context even slightly related to security, either the client or the network communication is usually easy to attack. So server must never trust client but must always validate everything.
- Over network the data is always serialized in some way, so the server needs some kind of parser. It might be a lot simpler than the one to parse the original input, but it is still a parser.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to some of the good criteria stated already, like

1. Round trips.  Putting the parsing on the client can make the interace seem much more responsive.  If the users commits a simple syntax error, the feedback, through syntax highlighting can be instantaneous.
2. security.  Allowing an unsecured client over an unsecured communication channel to send in a rich construct like a command object that will be executed without additional checking on the server can be risky.  Yes, you can check the command object on the server, but then You have the same code in two places. Not ideal.

**AND**

Barring other other overriding concerns, my primary criterion for this problem, is the choice of language.   I find it orders of magnitude quicker and error free to implement parsing logic or other complex logic in a robust, clear language, such as those that are supported on the heavy duty server platforms.  EG, implementing parsing in JavaScript, trying to trace through a language that refuses to even give me a compiler error, if I accidentally get a typo in my variable name, and instead, declares another variable!, versus, C#.